# Как вернуть state к предыдущему значению при неудачном fetch?

Tags: reactjs

подскажите пожалуйста, как можно вернуть state к предыдущему значению при неудачной отправке на сервер?

```
const Position = ({ value }) => {
  const [position, setPosition] = useState(value)

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        const { position } = await changePosition(position)
        setPosition(position)
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
      }
    }

    fetchData()
  }, [position])

  return (
    <Select
      value={position}
      onChange={(value) => setPosition(value)}
    >
      <Option value="left">Left</Option>
      <Option value="top">Top</Option>
      <Option value="right">Right</Option>
      <Option value="bottom">Bottom</Option>
    </Select>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно будет перенести API в сам handler и менять состояние position только в случае успеха. В случае неудачи, сохранять и показать ошибку. Ну и что бы не путать юзеров желательно показывать прелоадер.

```
const Position = ({ value }) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [position, setPosition] = useState(value);
  const [error, setError] = useState('');

  const handleUpdatePosition = async (newValue) => {
    setLoading(true)
    try {
      const { position } = await changePosition(newValue);
      setPosition(value)
    } catch (e) {
      setError(e.message)
    } finally {
      setLoading(false)
    }
  }

  return (
    <Select
      value={position}
      onChange={(newValue) => handleUpdatePosition(newValue)}
    >
      <Option value="left">Left</Option>
      <Option value="top">Top</Option>
      <Option value="right">Right</Option>
      <Option value="bottom">Bottom</Option>
    </Select>
  )
}
```